# Inserting images in table cell flush

Tags: html, html-table, cell

everyone. The problem with arriving late to the web design party, is that I don't know how to use tables or cells. I am trying to insert an image into a cell that I know has 215x145px and my image has the same dimensions, only to find extra space in it.

Actually, firebug shows quite different heights but I honestly don't know how to solve this. This is one of the most hated and frustrtating aspects of email campaigns, at least for me.

Any help is MOST appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
<table align="center"  width="725" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#0E6FA5"><span style="text-align: center; text-decoration: none;">
</td>
<td valign="top" height="145" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="215"
rowspan="2"style="border:0; padding:0; margin:0;"><span style="background-color: #FFF;
margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 145px; text-align: left;"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#0E6FA5">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

[image: Nasty white space in table]

Comment: I think it might help if your HTML didn't contain incomplete tags? You are missing several `</spans>` Can you show us more code, including your images? Feel free to use http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: oh. like I said, i don't know how to do this so I am using DW's tools. i'll post my code ASAP. thanx rlb.usa.

Comment: Here we go:http://jsfiddle.net/mauferrusca/F5yzG/

Answer (score 0):

Well, since I forgot to mention that this situation was FF-related only, I feel it's only fair to share the solution I found:

http://www.webmasterworld.com/firefox_browser/3274620.htm

> > When in standards-compliance mode (due to the doctype), images are inline elements, not >>block-level. You can usually fix the problem with the extra space (present to account for >>the descender of any accompanying text) by the following CSS:
> >
> > img {display:block;}
> >
> > Or by adding style="display:block;" to your img element.